# Merging reducer as a key in another reducer

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have a reducer `reducerA` that looks like this

```
reducerA = {
  A: [],
  B: {},
  C: {},
  D: [],
};
```

I have another reducer `reducerB` that looks like this

```
reducerB = {
  E: {},
}
```

What I would like to do is merge `reducerB` into `reducerA` and obtain something that would look something like this

```
reducerA = {
  A: [],
  B: {},
  C: {},
  D: [],
  reducerB: {
    E: {}
  },
};
```

Where changes to state variables A,B,C and D are triggered in `reducerA` function and changes in state variable E is still triggered in `reducerB` function.

I have already tried using `combineReducers`. But apparently, it combines `reducerA` and `reducerB` as children of a outer reducer. And that would require me to access the state variable inside `reducerA` as `reducerA.reducerA.A`

```
export default {
  reducerA: combinedReducers({reducerA, reducerB})
}
```

I would like to know if there is a rather clinical solution to the problem. I found quite a few libraries that do solve the problem. But I am still reluctant about them and would like to solve this without them if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const reducerA = (state, action) => {
  const newState = {}
  switch (action.type) {
    case someaction:
      newState = {
        A: [],
        B: {},
        C: {},
        D: [],
      }
    default:
      newState = {
        ...state
      }
  }
  return {
    ...newState,
    reducerB: reducerB(state, action)
  }
}
```

This should solve your problem. ;D

Comment: Beautiful and Ingenious.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you ask for is against the redux reducer concept and breaks encapsulation. If you want to create a reducer which relays on state of reducerA and reducerB, you should probably dispatch the *actions* which are dispatched be reducerA and reducerB respectively and don't rely on other reducers.

Anyhow, when you are using react-redux, I'd recommend to employ `mapDispatchToProps` where you can create a mapping of the global state for your component props, e.g:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return state.reducerA.foo + state.reducerB.bar
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```

Comment: What I am working on is kind of a legacy code. The code has perfectly fine running unit tests and is rigorously tested with both automated and manual test cases. So, If I am to use map state to props for accessing the already existing structure, there simply will be too many places that I will have to map them state to props. I was thinking if a solution existed that would be good to use, but since there appears nothing like so, I will be taking helps from libraries

Comment: Of course you could reuse the mapStateToProps method and avoid code duplication.

Comment: Would be nice if you could paste a link to a library which can fulfill your requirements here .

Comment: The answer marked correct did the work. The library I was about to use was  https://github.com/kuy/redux-merge-reducers